# Как перейти в предыдущие окно

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qstackedwidget

При переходе во 2 окно все хорошо, но когда надо вернуться назад, вылезает ошибка

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QStackedWidget

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(356, 300)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(336, 272))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 90, 161, 61))
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(161, 61))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 356, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вперед"))

class Ui_MainWindow2(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(336, 272)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(336, 272))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 90, 141, 61))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 336, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Назад"))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):                          
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self) 

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.forward)

        self.MainWindow2 = MainWindow2(self)

    def forward(self):
        self.MainWindow2.show()
        windows.hide()

class MainWindow2(QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow2):                          
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self) 

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.back)

        self.MainWindow = MainWindow(self)

    def back(self):
        self.MainWindow.show()
        windows.hide()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    startmenu_window = MainWindow()
    windows = QStackedWidget()

    windows.addWidget(startmenu_window)  
    windows.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: А что за ошибка? Добавьте в вопрос. У меня ваш код вообще не запустился -- там рекурсивные вызовы `__init__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал общее окно с `QStackedWidget`, на которое поместил оба виджета из вопроса. А чтобы было переключение перед окнами по кликам на кнопки соединил сигнал `clicked` к методу `QStackedWidget.setCurrentWidget`

Пример:

```
...
class MainWindow1(QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class MainWindow2(QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        window1 = MainWindow1()
        window2 = MainWindow2()

        stacked = QStackedWidget()
        stacked.addWidget(window1)
        stacked.addWidget(window2)

        window1.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: stacked.setCurrentWidget(window2))
        window2.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: stacked.setCurrentWidget(window1))

        self.setCentralWidget(stacked)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Весь код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QStackedWidget

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(356, 300)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(336, 272))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 90, 161, 61))
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(161, 61))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 356, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вперед"))

class Ui_MainWindow2(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(336, 272)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(336, 272))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 90, 141, 61))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 336, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Назад"))


class MainWindow1(QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class MainWindow2(QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        window1 = MainWindow1()
        window2 = MainWindow2()

        stacked = QStackedWidget()
        stacked.addWidget(window1)
        stacked.addWidget(window2)

        window1.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: stacked.setCurrentWidget(window2))
        window2.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: stacked.setCurrentWidget(window1))

        self.setCentralWidget(stacked)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```